# Perl's datetime not returning correct differences in time

Tags: datetime, perl

Inspired from https://perlmaven.com/datetime, I am attempting to find the number of hours of difference between 2024-01-03T19:00:00 and 2024-01-07T16:00:00 (93 hours).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use 5.038;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use DDP;
use Devel::Confess 'color';
use DateTime;

sub str_to_date ($date) {
    if ($date =~ m/^(\d+) # year
    \-(\d{1,2})           # month
    \-(\d{1,2})           # day
    T
    (\d+)                        # hour
    :
    (\d+)                        # minutes
    :
    (\d+)                        # seconds                  
    /x) {
        return DateTime -> new(
        year  => $1,
        month => $2,
        day   => $3,
        hour    => $4,
        minute=> $5,
        second=> $6,
    );
    } else {
        die "$date failed regex.";
    }
} # later dates are "greater"
my $wed_date = str_to_date('2024-01-03T19:00:00');
say $wed_date->day;
my $sun_date = str_to_date('2024-01-07T16:00:00');
my $diff = $sun_date - $wed_date; # returns a duration object

p $diff;
say $diff->clock_duration->in_units('hours'); # 21, but should be 93
say $diff->in_units('hours'); # 21 again
say $diff->hours; # 21 again
say $sun_date->delta_days($wed_date)->in_units('hours'); # 0
p $diff->deltas;
```

all of the methods that I have found from https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime::Format::Duration are giving incorrect answers.

Alternatively, if I remove the parsing,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use 5.038;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use autodie ':default';
use DDP;
use Devel::Confess 'color';
use DateTime;

my $wed_date = DateTime->new(
    year => 2024,
    month=>1,
    day=>3,
    hour=>19
);#str_to_date('2024-01-03T19:00:00');
my $sun_date = DateTime->new(
    year=>2024,
    month=>1,
    day=>7,
    hour=>16#my $sun_date = str_to_date('2024-01-07T16:00:00');
);#
say $wed_date->day;

my $diff = $sun_date - $wed_date;

p $diff;
say $diff->clock_duration->in_units('hours'); # 21, but should be 93
say $diff->in_units('hours'); # 21 again
say $diff->hours; # 21 again
say $sun_date->delta_days($wed_date)->in_units('hours'); # 0
p $diff->deltas; # 10
```

the answers are identical.

the DateTime::Duration object appears to be ignoring the days in between, and only focusing on the difference between the hours.

How can I get the correct # of hours between two dates?

Comment: Why not replace all regex parsing in `str_to_date` with two instances of `DateTime` with the values fixed? It is `DateTime` that does something wrong, right?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I think that the problem is in the duration object.  I've confirmed that DateTime is parsing correctly

Comment: _"DateTime is parsing correctly"_ - I mean, remove _your_ parsing. Remove the `str_to_date` function altogether. Instantiate two `DateTime` objects with fixed values and do the duration calculation and then show that it's wrong.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I've removed my parsing, but the error persists.

Comment: @con Good. That's what it means to make a MRE.

Comment: Tip: Instead of `str_to_date`, you could use DateTime::Format::ISO8601

Comment: @choroba, Re "*`in_units('hours')` is never greater than 23*", That's not true. See my answer where it returns 93.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `->delta_ms` instead of `->subtract_datetime` (the method invoked by subtraction).

---

A duration measured in days can't be converted into hours, since not all days have the same number of hours. In fact, only these conversions are safe:

- weeks ⇔ days
- hours ⇔ minutes
- seconds ⇔ nanoseconds

As such, `->in_units( 'hours' )` only converts the hour and minute components of the duration into hours.

`$sun_date - $wed_date` returns a duration of 3 days and 1260 minutes.
`->in_units( 'hours' )` returns int( 0 + 1260/60 ) = 21 hours.

The solution is to create a duration that consists of hours and/or minutes instead of days.

`$sun_date->delta_ms( $wed_date )` returns a duration of 5580 minutes.
`->in_units( 'hours' )` returns int( 0 + 5580/60 ) = 93 hours.

Answer (score 1):

the answer, according to https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#How-DateTime-Math-Works

```
$sun_date->subtract_datetime_absolute($wed_date)->seconds;
```

which is a DateTime::Duration object:

```
DateTime::Duration  {
    public methods (34): add, add_duration, calendar_duration, clock_duration, clone, compare, days, delta_days, delta_minutes, delta_months, delta_nanoseconds, delta_seconds, deltas, end_of_month_mode, hours, in_units, inverse, is_limit_mode, is_negative, is_positive, is_preserve_mode, is_wrap_mode, is_zero, MAX_NANOSECONDS, minutes, months, multiply, nanoseconds, new, seconds, subtract, subtract_duration, weeks, years
    private methods (8): _add_overload, _compare_overload, _duration_object_from_args, _has_negative, _has_positive, _multiply_overload, _normalize_nanoseconds, _subtract_overload
    overloads: *, +, -, <=>, cmp
    internals: {
        days           0,
        end_of_month   "wrap",
        minutes        0,
        months         0,
        nanoseconds    0,
        seconds        334800
    }
}
```

the number of seconds, 334800, is equal to 93 hours, the correct answer.

Thanks to commenters.

Comment: I love when making a [mre] works out into making an answer that may help others. Great that you posted your conclusions!

Comment: The reason you had to circumvent `->in_units( 'hours' )` and incorrectly calculate the hours yourself is because not all minutes have the same number of seconds.